# MSXML Out Memory -Delphi

Tags: xml, delphi, msxml

MSXML fails with out of memory when we try to transform XML about 160MB.

What is interesting about this is that it fails only for a certain server, I can transform the same file successfully without any issues on my computer.

Here are the things I tried:

- Increase Virtual memory -had no effect
- Already tried unloading the
  dll that helped for a while but once file size get huge again happens
  only on that server

I was trying to make my application large adress aware by setting PE flag but feel this might not work with delphi 5 .

Note: I know MSXML uses a DOM model and pulls everything into memory but we can't move from this model and have  fix this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
DELPHI 5
MSMXML 6

Comment: Have you tried defragmenting the drive on that machine?

Comment: if that seems an odd suggestion - perhaps http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx would explain my thinking

Comment: On analyzing my disk it has 14% fragmentation ,Is this what I should try defraging?

Comment: I still think it is worth a try, but my suggestion was roundly rejected by other contributors

Comment: This didn't work but I just moved to a different parser for my solution.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large address aware is probably your only hope. You won't be able to do that with the built in Borland memory manager. So using FastMM or even a replacement based of the platform `HeapAlloc` would get you over that hurdle. There may be other problems with large address aware and the RTL/VCL but I would be confident. I did all of this successfully with Delphi 6 so Delphi 5 shouldn't be out of the question.

Fundamentally you need to switch to a SAX parser. DOM based parsers don't mix with 32 bit address space and huge XML files.

Comment: What do you think could be the reason that it happens only on certain servers?

Comment: Virtual address space happens to be different. Perhaps the failing server happens to load a dll with an inconvenient base address.

Comment: Wasn't the old Borland Memory Manager prone to memory fragmentation?

Comment: @Silver I think so. The xml parser is not using that MM tho. It's MSXML. Anyway, 160MB and DOM and 2GB address space and Borland MM and long running server process is recipe for trouble.